# Why 'make' always rebuilds the target?

Tags: makefile

My Makefile is:

```
OBJS = b.o c.o a.o
FLAGS = -Wall -Werror
CC = gcc

test: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(OBJS) -o test
b.o: b.c b.h
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c b.c
a.o: a.c b.h c.h
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c a.c
c.o: c.c c.h
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c c.c
clean:
    rm a
    rm *.o
all: test
```

If I do `make` then `make` again, it always rebuilds 'test'.  Why does it do this?

Even if i do: `make a.o` it rebuilds... Im on linux if that helps.

In windows if I change 'test' by 'test.exe' and '-o test' by '-o test.exe', it works fine.
So I guess that for some reason 'make' in my linux cant check the datestamps of my files in the directory.

I FIXED IT!
The .c were created in Windows. I opened all .c and .h in vi, and without doing nothing save changes, and all worked. I think that the datestamp thing was fixed doing this.

Comment: Can you work up a simpler test case?  (Such as fewer files, perhaps a hello-world-type program, so you can include everything in the question.)  You've changed how the *test* rule works in a recent edit, and I suspect there are other significant differences from what's been posted.

Comment: I think the problem its linux.
If in that makefile I change 'test' by 'text.exe' and in its rule '-o text.exe', it works fine.

Comment: Just as an aside, you probably shouldn't call your executable 'test'. Most UNIXes have a real 'test' program.

Comment: @pax But it won't matter if he never puts his executable somewhere in PATH.

Comment: @Roger, that's a good point. It's just that I've been bitten before when `.` isn't on my path (and it _shouldn't_ be if you want to be secure). Then, when I run `test` instead of `./test`, I get rather unexpected results. Nowadays I always call my test programs `tst` (or `x` if I'm feeling pathologically efficient).

Comment: The convention is to use the variable `CFLAGS`.  Following conventions is a good idea, and will allow you to make better use of default rules.

Answer (score 17):

Your first rule is:

```
test: $(OBJS)
```

That means if a file named 'test' doesn't exist, the rule should run and create it. Since 'test' never exists (that rule doesn't actually create a file named 'test'), it runs every time. You should change 'test' to 'a', the actual output of that rule

For future reference, if a rule doesn't actually create the thing on the left-hand side, you should mark it with:

```
.PHONY: test
```

Comment: Im sorry, it was my typo.. its that way in the Makefile

Answer (score 4):

As a last resort you can run Make in debug mode (make -d) and comb through the output. Before trying that, I suggest you add a line to the "test" rule to see if there are any prerequisites that Make thinks require the rebuilding of test (and use some automatic variables in the compile command, as a good practice).

```
test: $(OBJS)
    @echo prereqs that are newer than test: $?
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify that *test* is a [phony target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets):

```
OBJS = b.o c.o a.o
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror
CC = gcc

.PHONY: all test clean
# 'all' and 'clean' are also phony

all: test
test: a

a: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o a

b.o: b.c b.h
a.o: a.c b.h c.h
c.o: c.c c.h

clean:
    rm a
    rm *.o
```

I've placed *all* first so it is the default target (which is common), removed the commands for compiling (make already has those built-in), and changed *FLAGS* to *CFLAGS* (which is the common name for C compiler flags and used by make's built-in rules).